# Add class to first row PHP

Tags: php

I have a loop pulling information from my database. How can I add a class to my first row without using jQuery?

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
                      echo "<div class='card-prod'><span class='card-title'>";
                      echo the_title();
                      echo "</span>";

                      foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
                        $keyt = trim($key);
                        if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
                          continue;
                        $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
                        $value = implode($values,', ');
                        echo "<span class='srch-val'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
                      }
                      echo "\n";
                      echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/dummy.png" />';
                      echo the_excerpt()."</div>";}
                endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a counter for that ($i):

```
             $i=0; 
             while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
                  echo "<div class='card-prod ".($i==0?'yourclasshere':'')."'><span class='card-title'>";
                  echo the_title();
                  echo "</span>";

                  foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
                    $keyt = trim($key);
                    if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
                      continue;
                    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
                    $value = implode($values,', ');
                    echo "<span class='srch-val'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
                  }
                  echo "\n";
                  echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/dummy.png" />';
                  echo the_excerpt()."</div>";
                  $i++;
                  }
            endwhile;
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this can produce unexpected results in certain circumstances.

Comment: Can you be more specific, @MrCode? Your solution is better (no need to use an integer here), but I don't see how we can have "unexpected results" here :)

Comment: @haltabush The integer/boolean difference is not going to make much difference. The difference between this code and mine is, here if on the first row `get_post_custom_keys()` returns false, the `yourclasshere` will never be applied to a row. Also, there shouldn't be a space after `card-prod` if that's the only class on the element.

Comment: !! You're right. I didn't paid attention to that (I just did a dumb copy&past)

Answer (score 1):

Keep count?

```
$count = 0;
foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
    if ($count == 0)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know if it's the first row, then by definition a boolean would be appropriate rather than a counter. This will work if `get_post_custom_keys()` evaluates to `false` on any of the rows.

```
<?php

$firstClassName = 'myclass'; // to be added to the first row
$firstRow = true;

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {

                $additionalClass = $firstRow ? ' ' . $firstClassName : '';

                  echo "<div class='card-prod" . $additionalClass . "'><span class='card-title'>";
                  echo the_title();
                  echo "</span>";

                  foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
                    $keyt = trim($key);
                    if ( '_' == $keyt{0} || 'pricing' == $keyt || 'vehicleType' == $keyt || 'coverageRegion' == $keyt || 'locationType' == $keyt )
                      continue;
                    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
                    $value = implode($values,', ');
                    echo "<span class='srch-val'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
                  }
                  echo "\n";
                  echo '<img src="wp-content/themes/cafc/images/cards/dummy.png" />';
                  echo the_excerpt()."</div>";

                  $firstRow = false;

                  }
            endwhile;

?>
```